# Grunt multi-tasks throwing EISDIR error when building

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

I am trying to set up grunt to minify a number of js files in a src directory and copy them to a build directory. Following the [grunt task documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks), I believe the below configuration should work.

```
uglify: {
    dist: {
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
          cwd: 'src/js/',   // Src matches are relative to this path.
          src: ['**/?.js'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
          dest: 'build/minified/',   // Destination path prefix.
          ext: '.min.js'    // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

When I run grunt I get the message

> Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>   Warning: Unable to write "build/minified" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.

If I switch the definition to use manual file paths it works fine. Is the documentation incorrect? or am I using it wrong?

I am running grunt v0.4.0rc2

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Hmmmm.

Comment: Update grunt and replace `src: ['**/?.js']` with `src: ['**/*.js']`

Comment: @mutil - Correct that was the issue. If you want to post your comment as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update grunt and replace `src: ['**/?.js']` with `src: ['**/*.js']`

For more information see the guide on [globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue where I  was getting an issue loading files of the structure:

`bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.min.js`

Apparently grunt struggles with directories that contain `.js` in them. I found this solution that fixed my problem: https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev/issues/29

Basically you explicitly remove the problem directories in the rev section.

i.e, this works:

```
rev: {
        files: {
            src: [
                'dist/**/*.js',
                '!dist/bower_components/Chart.js',
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the detectDestType function in node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy/tasks/copy.js as below:

```
var detectDestType = function(dest) {
    if (grunt.util._.endsWith(dest, path.sep)) {
      return 'directory';
    } else {
      return 'file';
    }
  };
```

It should fix the issue.