# Grunt build with Yeoman generated Gruntfile breaks with EISDIR error code

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm trying to run the default grunt build task with the Gruntfile.js generated file by yeoman.

This file is working for the generated app but as soon as I replace the files with the ones of my current app I have a warning breaking the process.

Here is the trace :

```
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
>> 31 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Configuration changed for concat, uglify, cssmin

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
Total saved: 0 B

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-04-13 14:28:10 UTC)
loading tasks   6ms  ████ 8%
svgmin:dist    68ms  ███████████████████████████████████████████ 91%
Total 75ms

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 12 files

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-04-13 14:28:10 UTC)
loading tasks    4ms  ██ 3%
copy:styles    131ms  ██████████████████████████████████████████████ 96%
Total 136ms

Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Minified 315 images (saved 1.39 MB)

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-04-13 14:28:10 UTC)
imagemin:dist  10.9s  ███████████████████████████████████████████████ 100%
Total 10.9s

Running "autoprefixer:server" (autoprefixer) task
>> 12 autoprefixed stylesheets created.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
>> 12 autoprefixed stylesheets created.

Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
File .tmp\concat\scripts\vendor.js created.
File .tmp\concat\scripts\scripts.js created.
File .tmp\concat\filters created.
Warning: Unable to write ".tmp\concat\scripts\" file (Error code: EISDIR).   Use --force to continue.
```

I don't know where this could come from.
It seems it comes from useminPrepare task which then call concat but I'm not sure:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT] my concat task is commented in the default generated Gruntfile.js

```
// The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
// minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
// to use the Usemin blocks.
// cssmin: {
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
//         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// uglify: {
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// concat: {
//   dist: {}
// },
```

Comment: can you post the config block of your concat task?

Comment: this is use full for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452751/grunt-multi-tasks-throwing-eisdir-error-when-building`

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem, I have the latest version of grunt and I don't have this pattern anywhere.

Comment: you must have a different concat config somewhere, else grunt wouldn't recognize the "concat:generated" task that it's running. How many occurences of the word "generated" in your gruntfile?

Comment: I have only one occurence in copy task of the "generated" word

Comment: Post your Gruntfile.js